# Subdomain on localhost gives Bad Request - Invalid Hostname error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using MVC. I want to test subdomains on localhost with IIS. What I have done to create a subdomain is:

1. I added a line to windows host file

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.0.1       abc.localhost
   ::1             localhost
   ```
2. I edited `applicationhost.config` as:

```
     <bindings>
           <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59322:localhost" />
           <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59322:abc.localhost" />
     </bindings>
```

3. I added following class to `RouteConfig.cs` :

   `public class SubdomainRoute : RouteBase
           {
               public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
               {
                   var host = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;
                   var index = host.IndexOf(".");
                   string[] segments = httpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Split('/');
                   if (index < 0)
                       return null;
                   var subdomain = host.Substring(0, index);
                   string controller = (segments.Length > 0) ? segments[0] : "Home";
                   string action = (segments.Length > 1) ? segments[1] : "Index";
                   var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                   routeData.Values.Add("controller", controller); 
                   routeData.Values.Add("action", action); 
                   routeData.Values.Add("subdomain", subdomain); 
                   return routeData;
               }
               public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
               {
                   //Implement your formating Url formating here
                   return null;
               }
           }`
4. Now To get subdomain name in controller:

   ```
   public string subdomainName
           {
               get
               {
                   string s = Request.Url.Host;
                   var index = s.IndexOf(".");
                   if (index < 0)
                   {
                       return null;
                   }
                   var sub = s.Split('.')[0];
                   if (sub == "www" || sub == "localhsot")
                   {
                       return null;
                   }
                   return sub;
               }
           }
   ```
5. My Index method is:

   `public string Index()
           {
               if (subdomainName == null)
               {
                   return "No subdomain";
               }
               return subdomainName;
           }`

Now the url `http://localhost:59322/` is working fine. But the url `http://abc.localhost:59322/` gives the error

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

What I am doing wrong. Why the subdomain is not working?

Comment: Please tell me if my question is not clear.

Comment: I asked this question 3 years ago and today again having the same problem, I also tried running vs as administrator, anyone?

Answer (score 7):

I know it is very late but for reference to others , just add in `applicationhost.config` :

```
<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59322:" />
</bindings>
```